# How to correct structure an asynchronous program to ensure correct results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a nodejs program that requests a series of XML files, parses them and then puts the output in an array which is written to disk as a CSV file.

The program mostly works, however occasionally the files end up in the wrong order in the array.

I want the order of the results to be in the same as the order as the URLs. The URLs are stored in an array, so when I get the XML file I check what the index of the URL was in the source array and insert the results at the same index in the destination URL.

can anyone see the flaw that is allowing the results to end up in the wrong order?

```
addResult = function (url, value, timestamp) {
        data[config.sources.indexOf(url)] = {
            value : value,
            timestamp : timestamp,
            url : url
        };
        numResults++;
        if (numResults === config.sources.length) { //once all results are in build the output file
            createOutputData();
        }
    }

fs.readFile("config.json", function (fileError, data) {
    var eachSource, processResponse = function (responseError, response, body) {
        if (responseError) {
            console.log(responseError);

        } else {
            parseXML(body, {
                explicitArray : false
            }, function (xmlError, result) {
                if (xmlError) {
                    console.log(xmlError);
                }
                addResult(response.request.uri.href, result.Hilltop.Measurement.Data.E.I1, moment(result.Hilltop.Measurement.Data.E.T));
            });
        }
    };

    if (fileError) {
        console.log(fileError);

    } else {
        config = JSON.parse(data); //read in config file
        for (eachSource = 0; eachSource < config.sources.length; eachSource++) {
            config.sources[eachSource] = config.sources[eachSource].replace(/ /g, "%20"); //replace all %20 with " " 
            request(config.sources[eachSource], processResponse); //request each source
        }
    }
});

var writeOutputData, createOutputData, numResults = 0, data = [], eachDataPoint, multipliedFlow = 0;

writeOutputData = function (output, attempts) {
    csv.writeToPath(config.outputFile, [ output ], {
        headers : false
    }).on("finish", function () {
        console.log("successfully wrote data to: ", config.outputFile);
    }).on("error", function (err) { //on write error
        console.log(err);
        if (attempts < 2) { //if there has been less than 3 attempts try writing again after 500ms
            setTimeout(function () {
                writeOutputData(output, attempts + 1);
            }, 500);
        }
    });
};

createOutputData = function () {
    var csvTimestamp, output = [];
    if (config.hasOwnProperty("timestampFromSource")) {
        csvTimestamp = data.filter(function (a) {
            return a.url === config.sources[config.timestampFromSource];
        })[0].timestamp.format("HHmm");
        console.log("timestamp from source [" + config.timestampFromSource + "]:", csvTimestamp);

    } else {
        csvTimestamp = data.sort(function (a, b) { //sort results from oldest to newest
            return a.timestamp.unix() - b.timestamp.unix();
        });
        csvTimestamp = csvTimestamp[0].timestamp.format("HHmm");//use the oldest date for the timestamp
        console.log("timestamp from oldest source:", csvTimestamp);
    }

    //build array to represent data to be written
    output.push(config.plDestVar); //pl var head address first
    output.push(config.sources.length + 1); //number if vars to import
    output.push(csvTimestamp); //the date of the data 

    for (eachDataPoint = 0; eachDataPoint < data.length; eachDataPoint++) { //add each data point
        if (config.flowMultiplier) {
            multipliedFlow = Math.round(data[eachDataPoint].value * config.flowMultiplier); //round to 1dp and remove decimal by *10
        } else {
            multipliedFlow = Math.round(data[eachDataPoint].value * 10); //round to 1dp and remove decimal by *10
        }
        if (multipliedFlow > 32766) {
            multipliedFlow = 32766;
        } else if (multipliedFlow < 0) {
            multipliedFlow = 0;
        }
        output.push(multipliedFlow);
    }
    console.log(output);
    writeOutputData(output, 0); //write the results, 0 is signalling first attempt
};
```

Comment: I suspect the for loop at the bottom. Since you're firing them all off at basically the same time, there's no guarantee that they will finish in the same order they were sent.

Comment: That is why I get the URL from the response object, then I check what the index of that was in the source array and insert it at that position in the destination.

Comment: I would start by debugging that logic in a debugger by placing a breakpoint there.

Comment: I suggest using promises. Great way to managing async operations.

Comment: Can you share the `createOutputData()` function?

Comment: if processResponse() doesn't need _this_, request(config.sources[eachSource], processResponse.bind({i: eachSource, url: config.sources[eachSource] }));

Comment: Can you confirm that the output file has always the same amount of rows as your input array?

Comment: @fxenik, the output file always has the some number of columns, 3 fixed data columns and one for each xml file retrieved. There is only ever one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Kevin B, you cannot assume that async callbacks will return in the same order of which you send them. However, you could ensure the order, by adding an index function on processResponse.

say you add the following to addResult

```
addResult = function (index, url, value, timestamp) {
    data[index] = {
        value : value,
        timestamp : timestamp,
        url : url
    };
    numResults++;
    if (numResults === config.sources.length) { //once all results are in build the output file
        createOutputData();
    }
}
```

and use an extra function to call your request

```
function doRequest(index, url) {
    request(url, function(responseError, response, body) {
        if (responseError) {
            console.log(responseError);
        } else {
            parseXML(body, {
                    explicitArray : false
                }, function (xmlError, result) {
                    if (xmlError) {
                        console.log(xmlError);
                    }
                    addResult(index, response.request.uri.href, result.Hilltop.Measurement.Data.E.I1, moment(result.Hilltop.Measurement.Data.E.T));
            });
        }
    });
}
```

then you can also change your loop to:

```
    for (eachSource = 0; eachSource < config.sources.length; eachSource++) {
        config.sources[eachSource] = config.sources[eachSource].replace(/ /g, "%20"); //replace all %20 with " " 
        doRequest(eachSource, config.sources[eachSource]); //request each source
    }
```

Comment: Adding an extra function call to wrap request() fixed the problem, it was not necessary to pass in the index. I've accepted your answer as it pointed me in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: happy to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the url to index code needs debugging.
Here is an example that uses an object that is pre-populated with keys in the for loop.

`

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require("fs");

var allRequestsComplete = function(results){
    console.log("All Requests Complete");
    console.log(results);
};

fs.readFile("urls.json", function (fileError, data) {
    var responseCount = 0;
     if (fileError) {
        console.log(fileError);
    } else {
        var allResponses = {};
        config = JSON.parse(data); //read in config file
        var requestComplete = function(url, fileData){
            responseCount++;
            allResponses[url] = fileData;
            if(responseCount===config.sources.length){
                allRequestsComplete(allResponses);
            }
        }; 
        for (var eachSource = 0; eachSource < config.sources.length; eachSource++) {
            (function(url){     
                allResponses[url] = "Waiting";
                http.get({host: url,path: "/"}, function(response) {
                    response.on('error', function (chunk) {
                        requestComplete(url, "ERROR");
                    });
                    var str = ''
                    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                        str += chunk;
                    });
                    response.on('end', function () {
                        requestComplete(url, str);
                    });
                });
            }(config.sources[eachSource].replace(/ /g, "%20").replace("http://", "")));
        }
    }
});
```

`